# virtual box library exports

Tags: virtualbox

I have successfully installed Vbox guest additions for Ubuntu guest.
The guest additions installs set of libraries. VboxOGL.so is one among them

My observation:
1. The VBoxOGL.so available on 32-bit Ubuntu guest exports OpenGL calls (e.g. glEnable etc)
2. The VBoxOGL.so available on 64-bit Ubuntu guest exports glx calls and have no OpenGL calls.

Why the above difference?

My intension is to use the OpenGL interfaces from VBoxOGL.so to run OpenGL demos. Is this ever possible?
With only guest additions intalled, can i achieve hardware accelerated graphics for OpenGL demos? How to confirm the same?